# Override UserID in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, userid

To import my crm data into Google analytics (GA), I linked the UserID of my users with ClientID in GA.

For this, I used the following code from GA documentation:

```
ga('set', 'userId', '432432');
```

Over time, the format of the User IDs on my website has changed - instead of the numbers, hashes are now used.

Can I now use the same code above, but only with new identifiers of my users, to send UserIDs то GA without damage current analytics?

In short, can I override the current User IDs in GA so that one user is not identified by the GA system as two different people?

Answer (score 1):

You can't overwrite the historical data already processed by Google Analytics, only those of the current day.

You could apply the new algorithm only to new users of the crm, from a given id on, leaving the same encoding (numbers) for the previous ones (users already processed by Analytics).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mapping table between the new and old ids there is a solution.

1. You need to take out the data from GA - historically. (You can use the paid service from Scitylana for this - you get data in BigQuery or in S3)
2. Then you need a copy of the new_id old_id mappings table in the database where you put the exported data from Scitylana.
3. Since you can no longer rely on the ga:userType variable (new/returning). You need to create a query that calculates it again using the consolidated new ids.

This can all be set up in a flow that updates nightly.
But you need to analyze via SQL or use a dashboard tool like Power BI, Data Studio, Tableau etc.

Since the data from Scitylana is hit-level you can calculate everything correct, no need to worry about double aggregations etc.
(I work at Scitylana)